# Flutter how to stop listening single firestore doc file (flutter 2.2 null safety)

Tags: flutter

I'm listening doc changes on a single document. But I have no luck to stop listening the file. It's keep listening even after `Get.offNamedUntil('/', (route) => false);`

```
@override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      var listeningNumbers = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('numbers').doc(myID).snapshots();
    
      listeningNumbers.listen((docSnapshot) {
        ...
      });
    }
}
```

How can I remove listener?

Answer (score 2):

[`.listen()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) will return a [`StreamSubscription`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html). Retain the instance in your state. Override [`State.dispose`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) and cancel the subscription there.

Comment: This is the correct answer.